# React Native Keyboard.dismiss() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

For some reason Keyboard.dismiss() is being very glitchy and random. I am doing something very basic. There are two different scenarios that invoke a Keyboard.dismiss() in my code.

1. if user scrolls the list
2. if they press Post

Both dismiss the keyboard momentarily but then it springs back up.. every once in a while it doesn't spring up but most of the time it does. This is only happening on android. Is there something I'm missing here? I even tried blurring the input instead but same results.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    Keyboard,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TextInput,
    Pressable,
} from 'react-native'

    const inputRef = useRef()

    const onScrollBeginDrag = useCallback(() => {
            inputRef.current.blur()
            Keyboard.dismiss()
    }, [inputRef])

    return (
        <ScreenWrapper paddingBottom>
            <HeaderBasic
                header="Comments"
                goBack={goBack}
                headerColor={{ color: colors.darkestColorP1 }}
            />

            <BigList
                data={listData}
                renderItem={render}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                itemHeight={90}
                getItemLayout={layOut}
                style={styles.bigList}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                onScrollBeginDrag={onScrollBeginDrag}
            />

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior="padding"
                enabled={isIOS ? true : false}
            >
                <View style={styles.cellOuter}>
                    <View style={styles.imageCont}></View>
                    <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={inputRef}
                            maxFontSizeMultiplier={colors.maxFontSizeMultiplier}
                            style={styles.input}
                            multiline
                            blurOnSubmit={true}
                            // onBlur={() => inputRef.current.blur()}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.postFaker}>Post</Text>
                        <Pressable
                            onPress={() => {
                                Keyboard.dismiss()
                            }}
                            style={styles.pressable}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.post}>Post</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScreenWrapper>
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
keyboardDidShowCalled = () => {
this.setState({
  siteNameModelBottomMargin: this.state.device === "tablet" ? 300 : 150,
  keyboardShown: true
});};
keyboardHideShowCalled = () => {
this.setState({
  siteNameModelBottomMargin: 0,
  keyboardShown: false
});
```

Use these above-given methods and import the statement mentioned below and call the methods where ever needed in your code. This may help you. Thanks!

> import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";